# How to print all the nodes in a tensorflow graph with the Java API?

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to print all the nodes of a tensorflow graph loaded with the Java API (which I called in a Scala app)
I would like to do so to retrieve information about a loaded graph (number of nodes, datatype of nodes, inputs/outputs of nodes, name of nodes...).

So far with the current java api (version 1.1.0-rc0) I only managed to print the informations of the operation by explicitly calling their **name**:

```
val operation = gModel.operation("opName")
val opName = inputOperation.name()
val opType = inputOperation.`type`()
...
```

Ideally, I would like to get the equivalent of the python toString method called when printing a graphDef

```
print(tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def())
```

Is there a way to do so?